# Can we close this gender-politics question?

Tags: discussion

This question [about a male gender specific job platform](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/38454/8146) is actually referring to (as near as I can tell) [to this site](http://ablystaffing.com/).

I don't know why the OP decided to change the gender in the quotes, but it is misleading, and would *imply* some sort of gender-related political message.

I don't think this site is the vehicle through which legal advice is meant to be disseminated, so the question is already off topic. It also seems to be a springboard for some sort of gender-related political message, and in the very least deliberately misleads in the language of the question.

Does this site really need to be embroiled in gender politics?

Comment: related: [Off topic questions have to be cleared out of the way, but NOT via closure](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251897/839601)

Comment: @JoeStrazzere i didn't want to assume that the OP was using us all as his or her personal guinea pigs.

Comment: I just cleaned up this question and actually put a temporary lock on it.